# Selecting data from SQL database

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am trying to select data from  'xxx_user' table, based on the usergroup the user is assigned to EG 'administrator'

Is there any way this could be done? And would it be possible to do it with a cron job?

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, username, password, emails, FROM $dbname";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Yes it can be done, and yes, with a cron job too. What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi well, i started with a execute command, but then realised that the group assignment for the user was held on another table 'xxx_user_group_map, so i stopped there. i can show you what i have, but it wont work based on what i just said.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but however normally one accesses a Joomla database from inside a Joomla application using the JDatabase object. See FFrewin's link in the comments.

Your example appears to be outside of a Joomla application, so your sql statement should look something like this, updated for your specific database schema, obviously.

```
SELECT id, name, username, password, email FROM `xxx_users` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `user_id` FROM `xxx_user_usergroup_map` WHERE `group_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `xxx_usergroups` WHERE `title` = 'Administrator'))
```

I can't see why you couldn't schedule it to be done by a cron job. For that I suggest a separate question/search on Stack Over flow for: scheduling php scripts.

nja